# Programmatically adding buttons to ScrollView (initially created with IB)

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I'm doing the majority of work in IB, and created a `UIScrollView` (with child View) using IB that I would now like to add `UIButtons` to (with corresponding constraints). I could add a few of these buttons using IB, but actually want to add hundreds of these buttons to a single `UIScrollView` so using IB seems fairly tedious.

Hence, I want to programmatically add the buttons (can copy/paste the button labels from a .txt file I have) in the `.swift` file.

How do I reference the `UIScrollView` created in the IB, in the corresponding `.swift` file, so I can add these buttons? See below code and comment:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "KeyboardView", bundle: nil)
        let objects = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)
        view = objects[0] as! UIView;

    let buttonTitles = ["Test Quote 1", "Test Quote 2"]
    var buttons = createButtons(buttonTitles)
    var topRow = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40))

    for button in buttons {
        topRow.addSubview(button)
    }

    self.view.addSubview(topRow) // how do I add this topRow view to the ScrollView created in IB, rather than to the main View?

    addConstraints(buttons, containingView: topRow)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add hundreds of buttons, maybe you could use an `UITableView` instead of a `UIScrollView` You then only need to create one custom `UITableViewCell` and use a datasource for configurating the UIButtons.